# Replace logo image upon scroll down JS / HTML / CSS wordpress website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I would like to have a logo image change (for the purpose of color) upon scrolling.

The navigation currently changes when scrolling downwards to have a dark bar behind it, does anybody have any suggestions as to what will work best for this image replacement?

I have tried using this as found in another SO question but wouldn't work for me....

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('logo_h logo_h__img').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#logo-img img')
                .css({'width':'184px','height':'33px'})
                .attr('src','logo1.png');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
            $('logo_h logo_h__img').fadeIn('fast');
            $('#logo-img img')
                .css({'width':'184px','height':'60px'})    
                .attr('src','logo2.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Filenames replaced for the sake of demonstration.

Thank you!

Comment: Your missing selectors in your code:
```$('logo_h logo_h__img')``` should be ```$('.logo_h .logo_h__img')``` if selecting classes, or ```$('#logo_h #logo_h__img')``` if selecting IDs. Try to update that in the code, see if that helps?

Comment: Hi, I have done this and it is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from @rlemon I have a script that works better, now implementing it is the task I am having trouble with!!

```
<!-- Logo Scroll -->

var img = document.querySelector('.logo_h__img img'); // get the element
img.dataset.orig = img.src; // using dataset is just being fancy. probably don't do this
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) { // add the event listener
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0) { // check the scroll position
        img.src = img.dataset.scroll; // set the scroll image
    } else {
        img.src = img.dataset.orig; // set the original image back
    }
});
```